# Format a "yyyy-mm-dd" date into "dd month yyyy"

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I have a variable in my program that stores the date in the form of **2018-04-21**. Now, how do I change the value into something like **21st April, 2018**?

I need something like:

```
var date = stringifyTheDate(actual_date);
```

What should I include in the `stringifyTheDate` function to do that?

Comment: Is this javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) this how you do it.

```
console.log(moment("2018-04-21").format("DD MMMM YYYY")); //prints 21 April, 2018
```

`MomentJs` is widely used library for date and time, if you are not using it then this is how you add it

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```